# What are Principal Attributes?

Tags: objective-c

I'm reading the documentation on NSTableTview and I see the term Principal Attributes. What exactly are Principal Attributes?

Comment: If you don't understand SO tagging, don't roll back changes made by someone who does.

Comment: Tone is everything.Don't be so elitist, I'm learning.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common heading in many of the other [class documentation pages](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22principal+attributes%22+site%3Adeveloper.apple.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=). It's another way of saying "these are the important bits of this class".